# Problem with SMTP and email header

Tags: apache, smtp

Why my emails that I sent using smtp at some email account at Hotmail have two "Received:" fields in email header?

```
Received: from NS1.MYSERVER.COM ([xx.xx.xx.xx]) by bay0-mc2-f11.Bay0.hotmail.com with   Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);

 Fri, 3 Dec 2010 11:30:13 -0800

     Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1] helo=mydomain.com)

by NS1.MYSERVER.COM with esmtpa (Exim 4.69)

(envelope-from <admin@mydomain.com>)

id 1PObKb-0007NA-Ii

for some_email@hotmail.com; Fri, 03 Dec 2010 20:30:09 +0100
```

If I do that using webmail there are three "Received" fields in email header.

Obviously there is a problem in settings of my server.

How can I determine what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly normal behaviour: Every server that processes your message will add its own "Received" ... "for..." headers to it.

- Your E-Mail client (in this case, the script) sends it to the SMTP server
- The SMTP server sends it to the recipient server
- The recipient server may pass the message on if so configured
  ...

Comment: @Pekka - I thought it has to do something with reverse DNS that does not match SMTP banner, which is the reason for marking emails sent from my server as spam or junk...

Comment: @Sergio I can't see anything in the headers you quote that gives an indication of that, at least not explicitly. (What you say can still be the case of course)

Comment: @Pekka I have a problem with reverse DNS and DKIM setup on server. I thought that can be the reason for this multiple received fields. Thanks...

Comment: @Sergio nope - as far as I can see, those headers are normal

Comment: @Pekka But the emails always get in spam or junk folder.

Comment: @Sergio that *can* have to do with reverse DNS not working, but it's a different issue, has nothing to do with the number of header fields

Comment: @Pekka I realized that now. Thanks again.